# Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method

Tags: java, test

Intento hacer un test unitario de una función que tengo en una clase llamada Validator. Esta función es publica y me esta devolviendo error. Pero la función test no es static y la función a probar tampoco es static , porque me pide que la haga static ?

Este es el test y donde me indica este error en validarCampoObligatorio:

> Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method
> validarCampoObligatorio(String, String, TipoCliente) from the type
> Validator

```
@Test
public void fechaMenorFechaActualTest() {
    String fechaSol = "20220330";
    
    CodRespuestaWS respuesta = Validator.validarFechaMenorFechaActual("FechaNacimiento", fechaSol);
    
    
    respuesta = Validator.validarCampoObligatorio(fechaSol, fechaSol, null);
            
    assertEquals("OK000",respuesta.getCodRespuesta());
}
```

Y la funcion :

```
public CodRespuestaWS validarCampoObligatorio(String nombre, String campo, TipoCliente tipo) {

    if ("".equals(campo) || campo == null) {            
        return new CodRespuestaWS(CodRespuestaWS.ER206, tipo + "Campo " + nombre + " Obligatorio no informado ");
    }
    return new CodRespuestaWS();
}
```

Comment: ¿Que es Validator? El problema está en que estas accediendo a un método de clase y no a un método de la instancia del objeto. prueba a ponerle static a `validarCampoObligatorio`, o por el contrario, instanciar un objeto de la clase Validator.

Comment: Crea un objeto `Validator` y a partir del objeto creado llama a la función `validarCampoObligatorio`. No puedes acceder a métodos de instancia sin crear un objeto de la clase.